# Close the overlay fullscreen menu when anchor link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, overlay

I am not good in Javascript, and I know this is very easy for some of you.
I adopted the overlay fullscreen menu from Codepen. I am trying to figured it out how I can close the overlay fullscreen menu when I clicked the anchor link.

snippet here

```css
@import "http://webfonts.ru/import/notcourier.css";
body {
  background: url('http://cs625217.vk.me/v625217712/1a11c/0QgZ5V0MWEo.jpg');
}

.lower {
  width: 340px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 50px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;
  border: 30px solid white;
}

.lower:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px white;
  border: 30px solid black;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.lower label {
  font-family: 'NotCourierSans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lower label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.overlay label {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background: url('https://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/img/cross.png');
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  font-size: 54px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  height: calc(100% / 5);
  min-height: 54px;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
  transition: color 0.2s;
  font-family: 'NotCourierSans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover,
.overlay ul li a:focus {
  color: #849368;
}

.lower~.overlay-hugeinc {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}

#op:checked~.overlay-hugeinc {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.overlay-hugeinc nav {
  -moz-perspective: 300px;
}

.overlay-hugeinc nav ul {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%) rotateX(35deg);
  transform: translateY(-25%) rotateX(35deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}

#op:checked~.overlay-hugeinc nav ul {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

#op:not(:checked)~.overlay-hugeinc nav ul {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(25%) rotateX(-35deg);
  transform: translateY(25%) rotateX(-35deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="op"></input>
<div class="lower">
  <label for="op">click the text</label>
</div>
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
  <label for="op"></label>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

can anyone help me to close the overlay fullscreen menu by adding javascript on the code?

Comment: add a click event for the menu a tag that unchecks the `#op`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( ".target" ).click(function() {
  $("#op").prop('checked', false);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url('http://cs625217.vk.me/v625217712/1a11c/0QgZ5V0MWEo.jpg');
}

.lower {
  width: 340px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 50px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;
  border: 30px solid white;
}

.lower:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px white;
  border: 30px solid black;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.lower label {
  font-family: 'NotCourierSans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lower label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.overlay label {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background: url('https://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/img/cross.png');
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  font-size: 54px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  height: calc(100% / 5);
  min-height: 54px;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
  transition: color 0.2s;
  font-family: 'NotCourierSans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover,
.overlay ul li a:focus {
  color: #849368;
}

.lower~.overlay-hugeinc {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}

#op:checked~.overlay-hugeinc {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.overlay-hugeinc nav {
  -moz-perspective: 300px;
}

.overlay-hugeinc nav ul {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%) rotateX(35deg);
  transform: translateY(-25%) rotateX(35deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}

#op:checked~.overlay-hugeinc nav ul {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

#op:not(:checked)~.overlay-hugeinc nav ul {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(25%) rotateX(-35deg);
  transform: translateY(25%) rotateX(-35deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="op"></input>
<div class="lower">
  <label for="op">click the text</label>
</div>
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
  <label for="op"></label>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="target" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="target" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="target" href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a class="target" href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a class="target" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```